# synthesizability of the code

Tags: fpga, verilog, hardware, synthesis

I got this piece of weird code in a text book. Simulation seems fine, the synthesis run returns an error on line #7... someone please comment on this piece of weird code... Iverilog has no issue whatso ever, only synthesis with yosis has problems with this code.

full text: Parser error in line input.v:7 syntax error

```
module synImplicit(dataIn, C1, C2, clk, dataOut);
input clk;
input [7:0] dataIn, C1,C2;
output reg [7:0] dataOut;
reg [7:0] temp;
always begin
@(posedge clk)
 temp = dataIn+C1;
@(posedge clk)
 temp = temp& C2;
@(posedge clk)
 dataOut = temp -C1;
 end
endmodule
```

Comment: http://www.clifford.at/yosys/nogit/YosysJS/snapshot/demo02.html  you can try it yourself

Comment: and hint: if you install verilog locally, it will even tell you more (namely, which character it did not expect), and that will tell you that things probably happen because the end of line 6 aren't in order!

Comment: you should, by the way, also add to your question that you're using the yosys JS online synthesizer demo: Basically everything else gives more in-depth synthesis info (I mean, I just know that demo because it's a very minimal demo, not because it's the greatest debugging tool out there)

Comment: there is nothing wrong with the simulation, only synthesis runs into problems

Comment: the thing isn't valid verilog, if your simulator tolerates it, then I'd argue there's something wrong with simulation.

Comment: In general, synthesis tools are not going to be able to deal with processes that have statements with individual delays. In this particular case, the delays are all the same event, so it is possible to imagine an equivalent state machine. But it's such a rare special case that it is not at all surprising that a synthesis tool would not have code to handle it. You'll have to convert it to the equivalent `always @(posedge clk) ...` process by hand.

Comment: I got this example from Thomas moorby text book , it so far has many many errors

Comment: `iverilog -v -S /tmp/foo.v` gives me:
`/tmp/foo.v:6: warning: Process not synthesized.`, so, um, your simulation is not OK, it basically doesn't do anything.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: It IS valid Verilog, just not synthesizable Verilog.

Comment: @DaveTweed huh? the `always` block syntax is `always @(condition) begin`, right?

Comment: do you have recommendation of a very good verilog text book? I want to do a 64 bit processor myself

Comment: @Marcus In testbenches, we can do like this, I mean only `always`, and inside `begin`, you can give timed behaviour with `@(posedge)` or delays. Similar to `process` in vhdl and then using `wait` statements inside. May not be synthesisable always.

Comment: @hardware Dump whatever book you are reading. Some of the fundamental books in Verilog which helped me was by J Bhasker's Verilog Primer and Verilog Synthesis Primer, he was part of developing the IEEE standards of the language. A bit old book anyway. Also Cliff Cummings Papers on V and SV.

Comment: @davetweed I ran iverilog with -S option, it says it can't synthesize always @(posedge clk, posedge rst) block, why? the error message, unable to synthesize synchronous process, wtf!!!

Comment: @MarcusMüller: No, not always (pun intended :-).

Comment: Again, in general, you can't synthesize logic that is triggered by more than one event. Vendor-specific tools have special cases that work when the target technology supports it, such as combining edge-triggering on a clock with an asynchronous reset. But it isn't surprising that a general-purpose tool like iverilog doesn't handle those cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a difference between what is allowed by *RTL* synthesis tools and *Behavioral* synthesis tools. Most people are only familiar with RTL, and behavioral synthesis tools have not had much commercial success. (Why that is true is an off-topic discussion)

RTL synthesis requires that you module sequential logic with a single clock edge and that clock edge has to the first procedural construct in the block.

Behavioral synthesis creates an implicit 3-state variable that indicates which set of code needs to be executed between each clock edge. The logic for reset also has to be implicitly created.

Comment: ok, i see, this is similar to the newest question

Comment: can you give me an example of the implicit 3 state variable behavior synthesis

Comment: https://web.uettaxila.edu.pk/CMS/coeADDbsSp09/notes%5CLecture%207.pdf